# Powerhshell4.0 variable cleared outside function

Tags: function, return-value, powershell-4.0

I have this code but the problem i'm facing is that my variable $RestartActionChoice outside my function is empty .. inside its 1 or 2 but when i enter the Try / Catch its cleared.. Can someone help pls.

Thanks,
    #Param
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    $Resource = Read-Host "Input Cluster Resource"
    $Application = (Read-Host "Application").ToUpper()
    $Stage = (Read-Host "Input Stage").ToUpper()
    $Cluster = (Read-Host "Input Cluster").ToUpper()
    $Group = (Read-Host "Input Group").ToUpper()
    set-variable -Name RestartActionChoice -scope global

```
function popup
{
#function to ask to failover or not.
$message = "Parameter : If restart is unsuccessful,fail over all resources    in this service or application?"

$yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", `
    "Enable the parameter."

$no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", `
    "Disable the parameter."

$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no)

$result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0) 

switch ($result)
    {
        0 {"You selected Yes."}
        1 {"You selected No."}    
    }
if($result -eq 0)
{
    $RestartActionChoice = 2
}
Else
{
    $RestartActionChoice = 1
}
return,$RestartActionChoice
}#End function
Try
{
popup
Write-Host -BackgroundColor DarkRed "RestartThreshold will be 3 by default"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things: remove the **return,** from the last line of your function, just state the variable $RestartActionChoice, that way the value inside will appear on the pipeline out of the function. Then assign that to a variable and show it in your write-host:

$result=popup

Write-Host -BackgroundColor DarkRed "RestartThreshold will be $result by default"

or just do this

Write-Host -BackgroundColor DarkRed "RestartThreshold will be $(popup) by default"